# Rails 4 View Not Converting Line Break/ New Line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, line, newline, break

I retrieve text from a database which has new lines contained within it.

```
@problem.description = "CPU utilisation continuously over 5 minutes\nDevice"
```

When that text is displayed in the view it looks like:

```
CPU utilisation continuously over 5 minutes\nDevice
```

but I want Device to be on a new line.

If I add to the view:

```
<%= @problem.description.gsub('\n', '<br>') %>
```

I get:

```
CPU utilisation of 99% exceeded 90% continuously over 5 minutes<br>Device
```

How do I get the view to convert the 
 into an actual line break and not treat it as part of the text....

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `simple_format`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: Then what about `<%= h(@problem.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>') %>` ?